# In Angular, is it possible to import mermaid from component instead of angular.json?

Tags: angular, markdown, mermaid

I am using Angular 14 and ngx-markdown 14.0.0 with mermaid plugin (integrated with ngx-markdown).

If I add "node_modules/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js" in scripts of angular.json everything works well, but I would like to load that big file only when my custom angular component loads.

For that I use in the component:

```
import "node_modules/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min";
```

but I get the error:

```
[ngx-markdown] When using the mermaid attribute you *have to* include Mermaid files toangular.json or use imports. See README for more information
```

The question is, how could I load mermaid script from the component and making ngx-markdown works?

Thanks in advance for your help.